# How to parse XML (in one huge string) with bash or ksh

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, ksh

Fairly experienced with bash/ksh scripting but not too familiar with awk. I've had a google but can't find an answer yet. Here's the problem.

We get XML files in, which are in the form of one huge string... The customer has requested we provide a breakdown, but with an average of 1.2k transactions in these files, it's not a manual job.

I've tried setting the IFS delimiter to  for example, but it's not working.
I've also tried setting the delimiter to '<' but that doesn't seem to play nice either.

So, how can I parse XML with bash or ksh? I'd love to seperate each record by its opening tag. Or simply put each one on a new line...

Thanks.

Comment: The best way to parse XML is to make use of a parser.  If you are using linux, you could use `xmlstarlet` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is we're working on production servers, installing/changing/adding requires approvals etc etc...

Comment: That doesn't justify using means that are unreliable and best avoided.

Comment: I'm not interested in politics or justifications, just interested in a way to do this!

Comment: If you can't do it using `xmlstarlet` then write a small parser for yourself, you can use `awk or perl` for that. Or best if you can use perl `XML::Parser` nothing in `bash` for you. PS I am not a politician neither I guess devnull is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the file using ksh/bash like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh

    IFS="<"
    printf "<%s\n" `cat $1`
```

Then above script would be used as following (assuming name is xmlparse.sh)

```
    ./xmlparse.sh $your_one_line_xml > ${your_one_line_xml}_new
```

You might need to adjust the result like deleting first line or you could play with IFS value so that you could split the file based on some tag name only.